# How to use amplify sign-in only?

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

In my angular application, I just want to use Amplify Sign-in function only. I don't want to use `Amplify UI Angular` since I have created my own login form. I want to pass the username and password to do authentication. I followed [the example](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/emailpassword/q/platform/js#custom-attributes), but not sure how to get it working.

I think that the code is simple.

```
async onSubmit() {
   try {
    const user = await Auth.signIn(this.loginForm['username'].value, 
    this.loginForm['password'].value);
   } catch (error) {
       console.log('error signing in', error);
   }
 }
```

Here is my [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/login-form-vmrhsv?file=app/login/login.component.ts), however it says that I miss some packages such http and https.

Comment: If authentication is the only functionality you wanted out of amplify, you can just use cognito directly

Comment: @jordanm, I am not sure how to use cognito in angular.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are calling `Amplify.configure` to configure which User Pool you are connecting to - https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/start/q/platform/js#re-use-existing-authentication-resource

you are using `Auth.signIn` correctly, but it needs to be configure with `Amplify.configure` **before** you can use it,

for example (no-angular specific):

```js
// ./index.js
import { Amplify } from "aws-amplify";

Amplify.configure({
  aws_cognito_region: "us-east-1",
  aws_user_pools_id: "xxxxxxx",
  aws_user_pools_web_client_id: "xxxxxxx",
  aws_mandatory_sign_in: "enable",
});

// ./components/sign-in.js
try {
  await Auth.signIn(username, password);
  let user = Auth.currentUserInfo();
  console.log(user);
  // {
  //   "username": "...",
  //   "attributes": {
  //     "sub": "...",
  //     "email_verified": true,
  //     "phone_number_verified": true,
  //     "phone_number": "...",
  //     "email": "..."
  //   }
  // }
} catch (error) {
  console.log("error signing in", error);
}
```

Comment: Can the code get token and apply it to the API call?

Answer (score 0):

You simply don't implement the front-end functionality to add a new user. Then, in your Cognito user pool config, there is an option User sign ups allowed? which you would set to `Only administrators can create users`.

Edit: Also, consider using the [hosted UI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-integration.html), it may save you some front-end work.

Comment: I want to deploy the angular application to aws sandbox. Is that the way?